# Is there a way to put a type name into a Rust macro?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```rust
trait Trait {
    const NAME: &'static str;
    const VALUE: i64;
}

struct Struct1 {}
struct Struct2 {}

impl Trait for Struct1 {
    const NAME: &'static str = "Aardvark";
    const VALUE: i64 = 0;
}

impl Trait for Struct2 {
    const NAME: &'static str = "Zebra";
    const VALUE: i64 = 100;
}

macro_rules! print_static {
    ($n:expr, $v:expr) => {
        println!("Value of {} is {}", $n, $v);
    };
}

macro_rules! print_static2 {
    ($t:expr) => {
        println!("Value of {} is {}", $t::NAME, $t::VALUE);
    };
}

fn main() {
    print_static!(Struct1::NAME, Struct1::VALUE);
    print_static!(Struct2::NAME, Struct2::VALUE);

    //print_static2!(Struct1);
    //print_static2!(Struct2);
}
```

It runs as:

```
Value of Aardvark is 0
Value of Zebra is 100
```

When I uncomment the `print_static2` lines, I get:

```
error: expected one of `,`, `.`, `?`, or an operator, found `::`
  --> src/main.rs:28:41
   |
28 |         println!("Value of {} is {}", $t::NAME, $t::VALUE);
   |                                         ^^ expected one of `,`, `.`, `?`, or an operator
...
37 |     print_static2!(Struct1);
   |     ------------------------ in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: expected one of `,`, `.`, `?`, or an operator, found `::`
  --> src/main.rs:28:41
   |
28 |         println!("Value of {} is {}", $t::NAME, $t::VALUE);
   |                                         ^^ expected one of `,`, `.`, `?`, or an operator
...
38 |     print_static2!(Struct2);
   |     ------------------------ in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Is there a way to specify the type name only once so that I don't end up doing something like this?

```rust
// Incorrectly associating Struct2's value with Struct1!
print_static!(Struct1::NAME, Struct2::VALUE);
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e873a1f116ab723e43e92c7e8b2b7fa)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to take a type as the parameter, say that:

```
macro_rules! print_static {
    ($t:ty) => {
        println!("Value of {} is {}", <$t>::NAME, <$t>::VALUE);
    };
}
```

Here's [the full list of macro parameter types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#metavariables).

Comment: `<$t as Trait>` is probably better to avoid accidental name clashes.

Comment: That was fast, thanks! @Shepmaster what would be an accidental name clash? If there are two macro arguments and you accidentally use the other one?

Comment: @wrongusername [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8f63610705d597686ebcd43a8569fb72)